# I am doing CRUD operation by using api.php from github and want to fetch id or name and save into a varibale

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

```
$response = call('GET','http://localhost/ProjectCamera/projectcamera/api.php/state');

$jsonObject = json_decode($response, true);

$jsonObject = php_crud_api_transform($jsonObject);

$output = json_encode($jsonObject, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

$state_id = $output->state_id;

print_r($state_id);

?>
```

Comment: From where on github did you get it from?

Comment: And what error are you getting?

Comment: https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api

Comment: ( ! ) Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp64\www\ProjectCamera\projectcamera\insertCity.php on line 31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `$jsonObject` is already an object you don't need to `json_encode` again with `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` instead you should use `json_decode($jsonObject)` this will convert it to stdClass Object then you can access the state_id property/field.

you can try the below code.

```
$response = call('GET','http://localhost/ProjectCamera/projectcamera/api.php/state');

$jsonObject = json_decode($response, true);

$jsonObject = php_crud_api_transform($jsonObject);

//If $jsonObject is an JSON object otherwise 
//If php_crud_api_transform is returning the array then you need to used json_encode but without JSON_PRETTY_PRINT

//BY passing true in json_decode second parameter will convert it to array
$output = json_decode(json_encode($jsonObject),true);

//you will get first state id
$state_id = $output['state'][0]['state_id'];

print_r($state_id);
```

Comment: ( ! ) Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\wamp64\www\ProjectCamera\projectcamera\insertCity.php on line 29                                                         For this line $output = json_decode($jsonObject,true);

Comment: ( ! ) Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp64\www\ProjectCamera\projectcamera\insertCity.php on line 31 For this line print_r($state_id);

Comment: Can you please var_dump `$jsonObject`?

Comment: After doing var_dump i got the data from my database but those two errors are still their

Comment: the output is as following(i will not attach the errors)

Comment: C:\wamp64\www\ProjectCamera\projectcamera\insertCity.php:30:
array (size=1)
  'state' => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'state_id' => int 1
          'state_name' => string 'Maharashtra' (length=11)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'state_id' => int 2
          'state_name' => string 'Andra pradesh' (length=13)
      2 => 
        array (size=2)
          'state_id' => int 3
          'state_name' => string 'Madhya+Pradesh' (length=14)
      3 => and so onnnnnn

Comment: I mean, can you please paste here the $jsonObject value after php_crud_api_transform($jsonObject) and use echo '<pre>';print_r($jsonObject) and paste the output as code?

Comment: Please replace this line `$output = json_decode($jsonObject);` with `$output = json_decode(json_encode($jsonObject));` hopefully it will solve your problem

Comment: :) No still error permits with these errors ( ! ) Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$state_id in C:\wamp64\www\ProjectCamera\projectcamera\insertCity.php on line 29
 AND ( ! ) Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\wamp64\www\ProjectCamera\projectcamera\insertCity.php on line 36

Comment: Are you accessing the right property? is `state_id` is available to access at parent level? can you print the complete `$jsonObject` here?

Comment: iam using mysql database in that database state is the table and in state state_id their, and no, i cant print the jSON object

Comment: As per your array in above comment `array (size=1) 'state' => array (size=7) 0 => array (size=2) 'state_id' => int 1 'state_name' => string 'Maharashtra' (length=11) 1 => `  it is better to change this to array in json_encode by passing 2nd parameter as true as below `$jsonObject['state'][] = array("state_id"=>1234,"state_name"=>"Hyderabad");

//BY passing true in json_decode second parameter will convert it to array
$output = json_decode(json_encode($jsonObject),true);

$state_id = $output['state'][0]['state_id'];

var_dump($state_id);`

Comment: @landgeshubham updated the comment with latest fix, hope this helps.

Comment: $response = call('GET', 'http://localhost/ProjectCamera/projectcamera/api.php/state');
$jsonObject = json_decode(json_encode($response,true),true);

print $jsonObject->{'state_id'};

Comment: No bro still stuck on the problem